# React Native Pass State from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a login screen with react native .

This is my index.js

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Wallpaper>
        <Logo />
        <Form />
        <SignupSection />
        <ButtonSubmit />
      </Wallpaper>
    );
  }
}
```

ButtonSubmit is a custom button that I created with some animation. I just dont know how to submit the form to my API once the user click the submit button because all the user inputs are being saved in the state of Form component

Answer (score 0):

You need to lift your state up into `LoginScreen` component. [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) explains it well. Use `state` of `LoginScreen` component and pass this state to `Form` component and `onChange` of inputs in `Form` component update `state` of `LoginScreen` component, for this purpose you can pass callbacks to `Form` component. At the end pass a callback to `ButtonSubmit` component and invoke it when submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In either way you can manage states using redux. Rather its better idea to use redux to manage the data.

You can go through this article to have more exposure.

https://medium.com/@imranhishaam/react-native-with-redux-for-beginners-6281959a2899

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data in the state to call an API, you would need to setup redux . Then you can call an action where you will call the API and set the API response in your reducer. The response can then be accessed in your component through props.

```
`//component

 handleSubmit=()=>{
//dispatch an action after performing neccassary validation
const {data}=this.state; //assuming the payload data to be in your state;
this.props.callAPI(data)
 }
 Action.js

 export function callAPI(data){
  return (dispatch)=>{
    dispatch(getData(data))
  }
 }

 function getData(data){
    //use fetch/axios to call the api 
   and dispatch another action to set the response in the reducer
 }



 //in your component, use connect({mapStateToProps},{mapDispatchToProps}) 
 (nameofYourComponent) and you can use your data as props.`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to setup Redux,
you can call a function on the button click,call the API and perform a setState for the response

```
`handleSubmit=()=>{
    const {data}=this.state;
    fetch(url,{add method,headers,body}).then(res=>res.json()).then(jsonData=> 
    {this.setState(jsonData)})
 }`

`render(){return(<button onChange={this.handleSubmit}/>)}`
```